# Rails mongrel with RVM fails to startup - mongrel_rails (MissingSourceFile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, mongrel

I'm having trouble with RVM and mongrel_rails getting along, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can happily start my Rails 2.x application with script/server using the Ruby gem mongrel.
Details:
which rails
/opt/local/bin/rails
which mongrel_rails
/opt/local/bin/mongrel_rails
which gem
/opt/local/bin/gem

However I've just added RVM with Ruby 1.8.7 and installed all my gems including mongrel but when i try to start my rails app with script/server I now get:
no such file to load -- mongrel_rails (MissingSourceFile)

Running a few checks I find:

which mongrel_rails
/Users/daniellewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@nacore/bin/mongrel_rails
which rails
/Users/daniellewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@nacore/bin/rails
which gem
/Users/daniellewis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/gem

.profile has:
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

(I'm using macports)

Any ideas on why script/server can't find mongrel_rails? I can only guess it's to do with .profile but I'm not sure what.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you have a newer version of "gem" installed inside of RVM than you do in your system ruby.   Downgrade your gem and it should work:

```
gem update --system 1.4.1
```

Comment: yip that fixed it alright.. I ended up updating gem for system to the latest and now just use rvm for all apps rather than system. Thanks Bryan!

Comment: Thumbs up if you're still using that in november 2013